# How to create a joint with sensor programatically?

Tags: gazebo-sensor, gazebo-plugin, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to create a joint from a plugin code that would look as follows:

```
<joint name="joint_a_b" type="revolute">
    <parent>link_a</parent>
    <child>link_b</child>
    ...
    <sensor name="force_torque_a_b" type="force_torque">
        <always_on>true</always_on>
        <update_rate>1000</update_rate>
        <plugin name="breakable_a_b" filename="libBreakableJointPlugin.so">
            <breaking_force_N>1</breaking_force_N>
        </plugin>
    </sensor>
</joint>"
```

I was able to create the joint using `physicsEngine->CreateJoint()` and setting it's properties directly on the `Joint` object. However, I can't figure out how to attach a sensor to it. A sensor that uses a plugin.
I tried to create the whole thing by creating an SDF object with the above XML and passing it to `Joint::Load()` method. But because that XML is not a full world or model description it get's rejected.

I also tried to make some sense out of `sensors::create_sensor` but I got stuck on the same problem with XML.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15941/how-to-create-a-joint-with-sensor-programatically?/) by [lubiluk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3157/lubiluk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,

you could use the logic from [Gripper.cc](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/57d297c1dd4ad978079c74abf8a6ee9352c6c9cd/gazebo/physics/Gripper.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Gripper.cc-78) to create dynamically soft breakable joints. See `fixedJoint` as example.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0